# Can Vim restore the state exactly after an undo?

Tags: vim

For example, if I'm in the end of a word and I type 'diwu', the cursor ends up at the start of the word.

Same applies if I have something selected in visual mode (after undo I'd like it to go back to the visual selection I had before the operation I've just undone).

Sorry if stackoverflow isn't the best place for this (seemed to be the best option looking around).

Comment: [SO is okay for vim questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su) (this is an edge-case, though as it is essentially a _usage_ question that _might_ end up getting a _prograaming_ solution). FWIW: I don't think you can since none of ``,``<,``^, etc. help you with that (not even after :lockmarks)

Comment: Ah ha. Thanks for that link. I looked around the various SE sites to get a feel for where these sorts of questions were ending up generally. Hadn't stumbled on that article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it can/should be automated with a mapping but in your first case I would create a mark with `ma` then do the deletion/undo, then type `` `a `` to position the cursor at the mark.

In the second case, `gv` reselects the previous visual selection.

Comment: I didn't know about gv. That's actually a significant step in the right direction. I tend to want to undo after I've changed a visual selection so I could make a mapping for ugv.

Comment: huh. I somehow missed the visual selection bit :) I knew _that_

Comment: One can also use `m'` and `\`\`` instead of `ma` and `\`a`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I came:

```
 the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy moon
      cursor here ----- ^
```

Execute

<kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>`</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

It requires you to explicitely save the location before the edit/undo so it is pretty useless unless you know beforehand that you are going to revert an edit

1. `ma`  (save current position in mark 'a')
2. `diw` (delete inner word, 'jumped ')
3. `u` (undo that change, cursor ends up at 'j' of 'jumped')
4. `` `a `` (jump to 'a' marker)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my use case is that I do something stupid while flying around the code so it's not an anticipated potential undo.

Comment: "*over the lazy moon*". moon? :P

Comment: @idyll: hey I tried coming up with a random-like non-dutch sentence :)

Comment: Moons are dogs in wonky UFOs. Backtick... Arf! madiwu`a

Comment: @CaseyJones Hahaha. "madiwu`a" is a nice touch